Python - PySide6 button click event not working after disconnecting and connecting new slot
I am creating some buttons and assigning click events to them. Each button is assigned to a dialog window where data can be entered. After entering that data it's sent to a flask server, flask server emits that data back to the client python application.
In the socket event, I am disconnecting the button and connecting a new click event. The disconnect seems to work fine, but connecting the button again doesn't seem to work.
I am creating some buttons and assigning click events to them. Each button is assigned to a dialog window where data can be entered. After entering that data it's sent to a flask server, flask server emits that data back to the client python application.
In the socket event, I am disconnecting the button and connecting a new click event. The disconnect seems to work fine, but connecting the button again doesn't seem to work.
def create_flow_layout(self)
    """ This is where I create the buttons"""
    
    # Looping through a list of locations
    for location in self.locations: 
        self.data[location] = {
            # Keys/values which hold the button and information related 
              to the button
        }
        button = QPushButton(location)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda checked, loc=location: 
                              self.open_dialog_logged_pallet(loc))
    


def open_dialog_logged_pallet(self, location)
    """ This is where I open a dialog which is related to the button"""

    # Basically just a few line edit's that are related to the location/button

    # After the line edits are submitted the button data is posted to a flask server and the flask server emits the changes


def update_buttons(self, data):
    """ This is connected to the socket event that the flask server 
        emits after the data from open_dialog_logged_pallet is sent to it"""
    
    # THIS IS WHERE I WAS HAVING ISSUES - The button would disconnect, 
      but the new clicked event was not applied

    for location, values in data['data'].items():
        button = self.data[location]['button']
            button.clicked.disconnect()
            button.clicked.connect(lambda checked, loc=location: self.open_dialog_logged_pallet(loc))

I tried experimenting with different things. I considered not allowing the flask server emit to self, but would be nice to get this functionality working.

The issue may be caused by the fact that update_buttons is called from an external thread, and since you're using a lambda there's no context for Qt about the target, therefore it will be executed in the original thread. Since open_dialog_logged_pallet will probably try to access UI elements, it will fail, as no UI access is allowed from external threads. While there may be ways to work around this (eg. using a custom signal), a more correct approach would be to properly call update_buttons in the main thread. Can you provide a proper [mre] that shows how that function is invoked?

@musicamante Yes, using a custom signal does seem to work and in my case might have to be the workaround since I don't think calling update_buttons from the main thread would work for my use case.
I am looking for realtime updates, so client A updates a button, Client B needs to be able to see that change.

Good. Then I suggest you to improve your question by adding a more comprehensive [mre] of the issue, and then answer your own question (click the related button on this page) by providing the solution.

So I ended up having to create a signal that would detect when the data was updated.
class ReceivingManager(QObject):
    dataObjChanged = Signal(dict)  # Signal to emit when data_obj changes

        def __init__(self, ui, api):
        super().__init__()

        self.data = {}
        self._data_obj = {}  # Initialize _data_obj before using the property setter
        self.data_obj = {}  # Now this uses the setter and is safe


        self.create_flow_layout()
        
                
        self.dataObjChanged.connect(self.handle_data_change)

@property
    def data_obj(self):
        return self._data_obj

    @data_obj.setter
    def data_obj(self, value):
        if self._data_obj != value:
            self._data_obj = value
            self.dataObjChanged.emit(self._data_obj)  # Emit signal when data_obj changes

   


def create_flow_layout(self)
    """ This is where I create the buttons"""
    
    # Looping through a list of locations
    for location in self.locations: 
        self.data[location] = {
            # Keys/values which hold the button and information related 
              to the button
        }
        button = QPushButton(location)
        button.clicked.connect(lambda checked, loc=location: 
                              self.open_dialog_logged_pallet(loc))

def update_buttons(self, data):
    # I now update self.data_obj with the data received from the flask server

def handle_data_change(self, data):
    # Since I updated the self.data_obj in update_buttons, this gets called because we setup a signal to call this whenever self.data_obj is updated
    
    # Now i'm able to successfully disconnect, and reconnect the buttons how I want. I use the location in the data here to reference the item I want within self.data


